# dynamodb: query with hash key only

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have this table:

- DomainId string HashKey
- EmailId string RangeKey

I was wondering if it's possible query this table with HashKey only, like this:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");   
var client = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
var dm = 'infodinamica.cl';

//Set params
var params = {
    TableName : 'table-name',
    KeyConditionExpression: "DomainId = :dm",       
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":dm": dm
    },
    Select: 'COUNT'
};

client.query(params, (err, data) => {
    if(err)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    else
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
}
```

ps: note that this table has HashKey and RangeKey.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Are you getting any error?

Comment: @notionquest. No, i don't getting any error. I am in design stage, and i want to know it this model can solve my requeriments, or if i need to set a global seconday index. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to query the data using Hash Key only using `query API`.

> Use the KeyConditionExpression parameter to provide a specific value
>   for the partition key. The Query operation will return all of the
>   items from the table or index with that partition key value. You can
>   optionally narrow the scope of the Query operation by specifying a
>   sort key value and a comparison operator in KeyConditionExpression.
>   You can use the ScanIndexForward parameter to get results in forward
>   or reverse order, by sort key.

Comment: It's also possible to use .get with hash key only, if you don't have range key defined for the table